# RFC Packet Diagrams Full List of Rules

Tags: rfc

I'm reading [RFC 7798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc7798.txt.pdf), and I'm having trouble understanding the notation on some packet diagrams, such as figure 5,6 from 4.4.2, and figure 2 from 4.1, so far. To be specific, it is the ' : ' from the first mentioned and the '+=' notation from the latter what I don't understand. This is not a huge issue, but I was wondering if someone could give me some reference that defined the rules for these diagrams.
PS: I have already read [RFC 2360](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2360.txt) but they do not go into detail on this matter.

Comment: i would assume "...OPTIONAL RTP padding" means optionally insert padding up to 32 bits boundary, so that packet size is a multiple of 32 bits / 4 bytes

Comment: some protocols require that packets align to the 4byte boundary and/or can use "length" fields which are given in number of 4 bytes, (e.g., ip header length).

Answer (score 3):

those are not notation but just [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) to render a schema in a text-only format.

For example the figure 2:

[image]

represents this:

[image]